# How to pass form action in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a issue in codeigniter.

When I pass the form like this:

```
<form name ="register" action="home/register" method="post"> 
</form>
```

it will generate the error:

> No Object found.

But when I pass the form like this:

```
<form name ="register" action="index.php/home/register" method="post"> 
</form>
```

it will work perfectly for me.

What changes should I make so that it will work without passing the index.php?

Comment: Use `site_url` answered by sanjong, if you are not using `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 5):

Modify .htaccess file in root directory of your project.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Hide the application and system directories like Javascript and CSS
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

[Here's the topic discussed on EllisLab Forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/155801/#777156)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name ="register" action="<?php echo base_url()."home/register";?> method="post"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the index.php from the URL, you can create a .htaccess file (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

> By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:
>
> example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article
>   You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example > of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified > items:
>
> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt)
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
>   In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is 
>   treated as a request for your index.php file.

Alternatively, There are two  ways to do it.

**Form Helper**

CodeIgniter has a built-in Form Helper to create the form tags: form_open().
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

**URL Helper**

CodeIgniter has a built-in URL Helper to automate the URL paths: site_url().
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: You can't getting my point
When we submit the form at that time we have to pass only conteroler name and action name but i have to pass also index.php otherwise it generate the error
action = "home/register" if i pass like this then it will generate the error

Comment: Correct, so you'll want the first suggestion I made regarding the .htaccess - That will remove the requirement of including the `index.php` from the URLs

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter there is a helper function called site_url("controller/action/arg1/../argn")

For your case it should be

```
<form name ="register" action="<?php echo site_url("home/register") ?>" method="post"> 
</form>
```

For more details follow this link

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the link like this , And it's work perfectly to my code

`<form name ="register" action="<?php cho base_url()?>home/register" method="post"> 
</form>`

Remember Must setup the config base_url path your domain or server address and define clear in htaccess.

Thank You